# How to setup FindFit function so that fitted function fits nicely to data points?

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit some data points to a transformed natural log function and transformed 1/x function. However, the fitted 1/x function fails to adhere nicely to the data points when x is growing larger. Below is my code:

```
pHBarListChurakov = {10.396067415730338`, 10.497191011235955`, 
   10.547752808988765`, 10.598314606741573`, 10.69943820224719`, 
   10.851123595505618`, 10.901685393258427`, 11.398876404494382`, 
   11.601123595505618`, 11.803370786516854`, 11.997191011235955`, 
   12.19943820224719`, 12.25`, 12.401685393258427`, 
   12.603932584269662`};
rhoOHBarList = 10^(pHBarListChurakov - 11);
calculatedUList = {-0.9000016984445702`, -0.5617336372971362`, \
-0.9009333610974087`, -0.40213804143299425`, -0.05513091822567246`, 
   0.5116416122750036`, 0.2772878238568564`, 2.0185896240329964`, 
   2.721886178225983`, 3.4101441103082335`, 4.350952842429438`, 
   5.258892468165652`, 5.84833335802726`, 6.659730475621987`, 
   6.6045283567870126`};
fitModel = k1/(x(*-k2*)) - k3;
fitCoeff = 
 FindFit[Transpose[{rhoOHBarList, calculatedUList}], {fitModel}, {k1(*,
   k2*), k3}, x]
fittedUFunc[x_] = fitModel /. fitCoeff;
fitModel2 = k1*Log[k3*x] + k2;
fitCoeff2 = 
 FindFit[Transpose[{rhoOHBarList, calculatedUList}], {fitModel2, 
   k3 > 0}, {k1, k2, k3}, x]
fittedUFunc2[x_] = fitModel2 /. fitCoeff2;
oriPlot = 
  ListPlot[Transpose[{rhoOHBarList, calculatedUList}], 
   PlotLabel -> "var vs Bulk OH Conc (mMol/L)"];
fittedPlot = 
  Plot[fittedUFunc[x], {x, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {"1/x"}];
fittedPlot2 = 
  Plot[fittedUFunc2[x], {x, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {"ln(x)"}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
Show[fittedPlot, fittedPlot2, oriPlot, 
 PlotLabel -> "Calculated & Fitted u vs Bulk OH conc", 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {-20, 7}]
```

Here is the output:
[image]
I want the transformed 1/x function to satisfy 2 requirements as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A model which fullfills both requirements is `fit[x]=(k1 + k2 x + k3 x^2)/(x + k4 x^2)`

```
Asymptotic[(k1 + k2 x + k3 x^2)/(x + k4 x^2), x -> 0] (* k1/x*)
Asymptotic[(k1 + k2 x + k3 x^2)/(x + k4 x^2), x -> Infinity](*k3/k4*)


fit = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{rhoOHBarList, calculatedUList}], (
  k1 + k2 x + k3 x^2)/(x + k4 x^2), {k1, k2 , k3, k4}, x, 
  Method -> "NMinimize" ]

    Show[{ListPlot[Transpose[{rhoOHBarList, calculatedUList}]], 
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image]